# Slowly changing Dimension always updating

Tags: sql, ssis, collation, scd

I have a dimension to load which has a field called `description` with a data type of `VARCHAR(50)`. Its collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CS_AS and it contains Arabic data such as "مركز العقبة". Its source has the same type, size and collation, but every time I load the dimension this field gets updated! Why does this happen?

Comment: Every time when you load the same file, same record, the filed is updated? Have you tried to load exactly same file, same record multiple times? Have you compared the loaded new "description" with old value to see if there is difference?

Comment: yes i do that, thank you for your replay , the problem has been solved  by changing database and the tables collation to Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it -- on Stack Overflow it's fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the collation of both your database and the tables is the same.  Specifically you should set them both to Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS as your comment suggests.